# primitive accessors in this example

Tags: objective-c, core-data, primitive, accessor

Could someone help me understand the primitive accessors with this example : i don't understand what is automatically set and the order of those methods :

1.after a person is created, is `willSave` the first method called? (i guess so, because `save:` is called after we create a person with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` )

2.in RootViewController (the second chunk of code), we then call the getter of `eyeColor` with : `person.eyeColor` :
a) in `eyeColor`, we call : `[self eyeColorData]` ,
b) **but** `setPrimitiveEyeColorData` is in `willSave`, which is accessible only if `primitiveEyeColor` exists,
c) **but** `setPrimitiveEyeColor` is in `eyeColor` and only called if `[self eyeColorData]` exists. So, i'm a bit confused with this code, could someone help me?

here's the code about `eyeColor` and `eyeColorData` :

```
@dynamic eyeColorData;
@dynamic eyeColor;

@interface AWPerson (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (UIColor *)primitiveEyeColor;
- (void)setPrimitiveEyeColor:(UIColor *)value; 
- (NSData *)primitiveEyeColorData;
- (void)setPrimitiveEyeColorData:(NSData *)value;

@end

+ (id)personInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    return [NSEntityDescription 
            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
            inManagedObjectContext:moc];
}

+ (id)randomPersonInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    AWPerson *randomPerson = [self personInManagedObjectContext:moc];
    //...
    randomPerson.eyeColor = [self randomColor]; //setter eyeColor
    return randomPerson;
}

+ (UIColor *)randomColor {
    static NSArray *colorsArray = nil;

    if( !colorsArray ) {
        colorsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                       [UIColor blueColor],
                       [UIColor greenColor], nil];
    }

    int randomIndex = arc4random() % [colorsArray count];
    return [colorsArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}

- (void)willSave {
    UIColor *color = [self primitiveEyeColor];
    if( color ) {
        [self setPrimitiveEyeColorData:
         [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color]];
    } else {
        [self setPrimitiveEyeColorData:nil];
    }

    [super willSave];
}

- (UIColor *)eyeColor {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"eyeColor"];
    UIColor *tmpValue = [self primitiveEyeColor];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"eyeColor"];
    if( tmpValue ) return tmpValue;

    NSData *colorData = [self eyeColorData];
    if( !colorData ) return nil;

    tmpValue = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
    [self setPrimitiveEyeColor:tmpValue];

    return tmpValue;
}
```

in RootViewController :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AWPerson *person = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setBackgroundColor:person.eyeColor];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT - Added info on `willSave`**
To answer your first question, willSave is called whenever the object is saved (using the `save` method).  So the first method called will be one of the class methods (used to create the object) or init and then, since you said that the object is saved just after it is created, willSave gets called.

I think the key to understanding this is to realize that `eyeColor`, `primitiveEyeColor`, and their setters are all ultimately interacting with the same variable in memory (the iVar named eyeColor).  The difference is whether or not the code in the setter/getter (in this case the `- (UIColor *)eyeColor {` function) is called.

There are just a few different ways to interact with it:

1. `[self primitiveEyeColor];`                  - This reads the value of the iVar directly.
2. `[self setPrimitiveEyeColor:tmpValue];`      - This sets the value of the iVar directly.
3. `[self eyeColor]`                            - This calls the `- (UIColor *)eyeColor` method in your class (which should ultimately retrieve the iVar or a representation of it).
4. `[self setEyeColor:value]`                   - This calls the `- (void)setEyeColor:(UIColor *)newColor` method in your class.  Note that in this case it doesn't exist so it simply calls the primitive method (and does the KVO magic).

In this particular code, they are using a "non-standard persistent attribute" because NSManagedObject does not support UIColor's.  Read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html).

**EDIT 2**
To answer your other questions:

> a) The color in `randomPerson.eyeColor = [self randomColor]` is
>   accessible with `[self primitiveEyeColor]` (in `willSave`)?

Yes, once eyeColor is set (either via the `setEyeColor` method or the `setPrimitiveEyeColor` method), you can read it from `primitiveEyeColor` and it will return the same value. 
Note that once it is set, `eyeColor` and `primitiveEyeColor` return the same value and can be called from anywhere in your class (not just `willSave`).

> b) So if `[self primitiveEyeColor] != nil` : in `eyeColor`, the line :
>   `if( tmpValue ) return tmpValue;` should therefore always be true...
>   when can we unarchive `eyeColorData` if `UIColor *tmpValue = [self
>   primitiveEyeColor]` is always returned in `-(UIColor *)eyeColor`?

This method only looks at `eyeColorData` (which was stored during the last call to `willSave`) if `eyeColor` is nil.  This is an optimization because we could skip all of this and just unarchive `eyeColorData` every time if we wanted to.  In this case, once a value is unarchived or set to a new value, it always stores that value and returns **it** so that we don't have to call unarchive again.

Also, there is really what I believe to be an error here (although it could be by design).  Let's say that we perform the following steps:

1. Set `eyeColor` to a random color (let's say blue).
2. save the object.
3. Set `eyeColor` to nil

Now, if you check the color using `[self eyeColor]` it will see that primitiveEyeColor is `nil` and unarchive `eyeColorData` again, therefore returning the blue color that was stored previously.  You should probably be over-riding the set function so that it sets `eyeColorData` to `nil` when `eyeColor` is set to `nil`.  That way, checking the value of `eyeColor` after setting it to `nil` will return `nil` as expected.

Comment: thanks lnafziger, a) the color in `randomPerson.eyeColor = [self randomColor]` is accessible with `[self primitiveEyeColor]` (in `willSave`)? b) so if `[self primitiveEyeColor] != nil` : in `eyeColor`, the line : `if( tmpValue ) return tmpValue;` should therefore always be true... when can we unarchive `eyeColorData` if `UIColor *tmpValue = [self primitiveEyeColor]` is always returned in `-(UIColor *)eyeColor`? thanks again

Comment: I updated my answer to address these questions so that I would have more room.  :)

Comment: thanks! about your n°3 : where do we set `eyeColor` to nil after we save the object?

Comment: This code doesn't.  I was saying **IF** you set it to nil after saving then this will be a problem.

Comment: thanks, ok, sorry but i'm still misunderstanding something: the first time we want to retrieve/unarchive the value `eyeColorData` : if  `primitiveEyeColor` does exist, it returns the value of type UIColor in `- (UIColor *)eyeColor`, and we don't unarchive the data from `colorData` ... afterwards, i get what you say : "so that we don't have to call unarchive again", but what about the first time `- (UIColor *)eyeColor {` is called?  it seems to me that we stop at `if( tmpValue ) return tmpValue;` because `[self primitiveEyeColor]` returns the value from `...= [self randomColor]`

Comment: The first time, `eyeColor` will be `nil` so it sets `tmpValue` to `nil`.  Then the line `if (tmpValue) return tmpValue;` means "if `tmpValue` is not `nil` return that value otherwise continue".

Comment: sorry i'm confused, isn't it in this order : 1.`randomPerson.eyeColor = [self randomColor];` , then 2.`-(void)willSave { UIColor *color = [self primitiveEyeColor];` returns the color set in 1), then in RootVC 3.`[cell setBackgroundColor:person.eyeColor];`, then `if( tmpValue ) return tmpValue;` ? in this order, `tmpValue` always contains a value, isn't it? Thanks again for your help, i really appreciate

Comment: Yes, in this case.  However if you don't set the eye color (in step 1) first, it will check to see if you have previously stored the value.

Comment: alright ;) i got it, thank you very much for staying in this conversation ;) i appreciated, thanks!